# System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed throws when the RSS document includes a <script> block embedded in an element

Tags: .net, xml, rss, xmlreader, syndication-feed

The code:

```
using (XmlReader xmlr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(allXml)))
{
    var items = from item in SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlr).Items
        select item;
}
```

The exception:

```
Exception: System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected node type Element. 
   ReadElementString method can only be called on elements with simple or empty content. Line 11, position 25.
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadElementString()
   at System.ServiceModel.Syndication.Rss20FeedFormatter.ReadXml(XmlReader reader, SyndicationFeed result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Syndication.Rss20FeedFormatter.ReadFeed(XmlReader reader)
   at System.ServiceModel.Syndication.Rss20FeedFormatter.ReadFrom(XmlReader reader)
   at System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed.Load[TSyndicationFeed](XmlReader reader)
   at System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at Ionic.ToolsAndTests.ReadRss.Run() in c:\dev\dotnet\ReadRss.cs:line 90
```

The XML content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/roller-ui/styles/rss.xsl" media="screen"?><rss version="2.0" 
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" >
<channel>
  <title>Software architecture, software engineering, and Renaissance Jazz</title>
  <link>https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/gradybooch</link>
  <atom:link rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/gradybooch/feed/entries/rss?lang=en" />
  <description>Software architecture, software engineering, and Renaissance Jazz</description>
  <language>en-us</language>
  <copyright>Copyright <script type='text/javascript'> document.write(blogsDate.date.localize (1273534889181));</script></copyright>
  <lastBuildDate>Mon, 10 May 2010 19:41:29 -0400</lastBuildDate>
```

As you can see, on line 11, at position 25, there's a script block inside the `<copyright>` element.

Other [people have reported similar errors](http://www.bing.com/search?q="ReadElementString+method+can+only+be+called+on+elements"&FORM=QBHP) with other XML documents.

The way I worked around this was to do a StreamReader.ReadToEnd, then do Regex.Replace on the result of that to yank out the script block, before 
passing the modified string to XmlReader.Create().  Feels like a hack.

---

1. Has anyone got a better approach?  I don't like this because I have to read in a 125k string into memory.
2. Is it valid rss to include "complex content" like that - a script block inside an element?

Comment: Look at the XSD for RSS and see what content is valid for the `<copyright>` element. Most likely just text.

Comment: well there is no formal RSS2.0 XSD, but Jorgen Thelin built one that is pretty good, available at http://rss2schema.codeplex.com/. The *formal* definition of RSS 2.0 is provided in an english-language HTML document: http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html . There's no W3C type specified for the copyright element, or any element. There are only examples. In the XSD schema from Thelin, the copyright is xs:string, which means it must not include angle brackets. Ya, I think the rss rendered by IBM in this case is broken, non-compliant.  But browsers swallow it, because they do script.

Comment: ps: Embedding javascript into RSS seems like a gross violation of one or more moral or aesthetic standards.

Comment: maybe enclose content into CDATA section?

Comment: Gopher, I guess that would work, except it's not my RSS feed.  It's from ibm.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `XmlTextReader` and override `ReadElementString` to skip or modify the offending element as it's being read.  Still feels like a hack but at least avoids the pre-processing with regex.

Here's a simple implementation that gets the job done:

```
class BrokenFeedXmlReader : XmlTextReader 
{
    // Additional XmlTextReader constructors can be added in 
    // similar fashion as needed
    public BrokenFeedXmlReader(TextReader input)
        : base(input)
    {
    }

    public override string ReadElementString()
    {
        if ("copyright" == Name)
        {
            base.Skip();
            return String.Empty; 
        }

        return base.ReadElementString();
    }            
}
```

Your example code would then look something like this:

```
using (XmlReader xmlr = new BrokenFeedXmlReader(new StringReader(allXml)))
{
    var items = from item in SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlr).Items
                select item;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was nearly exactly what I needed. The RSS I am parsing has a "img ... />" html image tag in the description start, resulting in the same error. I did a hacky workaround to get the inner XML without the img tag. Good enough for my case.

<code>
if ("description" == Name)
  {
   var innerXml = ReadInnerXml();
   var closingHtmlTagIndex = innerXml.LastIndexOf("/>");
   return closingHtmlTagIndex <= 0 ? innerXml : innerXml.Substring(closingHtmlTagIndex + 2).Trim();
  }
</code>